# Explanation of error in WolframAlpha

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha

I wanted to find the following antiderivative $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}.$$ Obviously, this does only make sense (when working with real numbers) on the interval $(0,1)$. So essentially we want to find $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}.$$ In fact, that computation is the same as finding $$\int \frac{dx}{0.25-(x-0.5)^2}.$$ It is easy check that the solution $$\arcsin(2x-1)+c.$$

However, WolframAlpha's answer is a bit different $$\frac{2 \sqrt{x - 1} \sqrt{x} \log(\sqrt{x - 1} + \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{-(x - 1) x}} + c.$$

However, in the real case (remember $x \in (0,1)$) WolframAlpha's answer does not make sense because we have the square root of a negative number $x-1$.

Does anybody know what is happening there and why WA tries to solve the integral in that way?

Comment: Another bug in WA....what else is new?

Comment: I'm not sure I would call that a bug. Maybe miscommunication or mis-aligned expectations between humans and computers: Mathematica and WA do not know that $x$ is supposed to be real; with that assumption, their answer is closer to what humans expect. Try "Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[1 - x]), {x, 0, t},  
 Assumptions -> t > 0 && t < 1]"

Answer (score 1):

The two answers are equivalent, as they differ by a constant. We can show this by showing that the derivative of their difference is zero. As you're already working with WolframAlpha, you might use it to check by simply entering the following:

[simplify diff (2sqrt(x-1)sqrt(x)log(sqrt(x-1)+sqrt(x)))/sqrt(x(1-x))-asin(2x-1)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20diff%20(2sqrt(x-1)sqrt(x)log(sqrt(x-1)%2Bsqrt(x)))%2Fsqrt(x(1-x))-asin(2x-1))

The result is zero. We can also find what the constant is by plugging in a convenient number, like $x=1/2$. We can also do this in WolframAlpha:

[(2sqrt(x-1)sqrt(x)log(sqrt(x-1)+sqrt(x)))/sqrt(x(1-x))-asin(2x-1) /. x->1/2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2sqrt(x-1)sqrt(x)log(sqrt(x-1)%2Bsqrt(x)))%2Fsqrt(x(1-x))-asin(2x-1)%20%2F.%20x-%3E1%2F2)

We find that the difference is $-\pi/2$.

On the other hand, while the answers are equivalent, the WolframAlpha answer is more complicated than it might be. *But*, if you ask WolframAlpha to show its steps, you get exactly the answer that you were looking for:

[image]